# Will this mock be visibile outside of this test?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I see a test that has a `jest.mock` call outside of a `describe` block.

I am concerned this will create a change visible outside of the test. I do not want this test affecting other tests.

Should `jest.mock` be moved inside the describe block or is it OK as-is?

```
import target from '../';

jest.mock('../../../helpers/helpers.api', () => ({
    httpPost(...args) {
        return args;
    }
}));

describe('my component', () => {
    it('should foo', () => {
        //... 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand, your example is fine as-is.

> Modules that are mocked with `jest.mock` are mocked only for the file that calls `jest.mock`. Another file that imports the module will get the original implementation even if run after the test file that mocks the module.

– https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestmockmodulename-factory-options